# Bookmark Lookup

Tags: sql-server, indexing, sql-server-2000

I see a node named "Bookmark Lookup" in my execution plan.

What does it means? It costs most among steps inside the plan. 
Any suggestion to optimize it?

Comment: Hope this helps .... http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Performance+Tuning/bookmarklookups/1899/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means the optimiser uses a non-clustered (NC) index first, then uses the NC->C pointer/bookmark into the clustered index (which is your data) to get more data. And yes, it's expensive usually.

You'd use a "[covering index](http://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/)" to remove the lookup so all data part of the NC index (the link explains what I've just said above too)

Answer (score 1):

You might find this free ebook from Redgate useful http://downloads.red-gate.com/ebooks/HighPerformanceSQL_ebook.zip